# I need single sql query fetch the result as mentioned output

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  case    list
1   case1   list1
2   case1   list2
3   case1   list3
4   case2   list4
5   case2   list5
6   case3   list6
```

output i need

```
1 case1 list1/list2/list3
2 case2 list4/list5
3 case3 list6
```

Comment: there is no question that i can answer sorry ;)

Comment: i have mentioned the question in the title. I need a query that fetches output like i have mentioned  in the section "output i need".

Comment: group_concat, or similar?

Comment: @jarlh 
 
group_concat worked for me.Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your output can be generated like that using SQL  what you need is to group lists based on cases so try :

```
  SELECT  `the_case` , GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT  `the_list` 
  SEPARATOR  '/' ) AS  `list` 
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY  `the_case` 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[image]

Read more about [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

[Read more about GROUP_CONCAT here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

**Query**

```
SELECT `case`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `list` SEPARATOR '/') as `list`
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY `case`;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef7ed/2)

Comment: Please mark it as answer, if this solved your problem